# Importing font and using it in ggplot

Tags: r, fonts

I imported my font via:

```
font_import(paths = "/Users/asuna/Desktop/",prompt = F)
font_import()
```

loaded fonts:

```
 loadfonts(device="postscript")
```

and then I try to use the font, however

```
ggplot(data.frame(df,x=c(1, 15)),  aes(x=x), aes(y=y)) + 
  stat_function(fun=h)+ geom_point(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))+ 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Cormorant Light"))+
  labs(y ="Y axis", x = "X axis")+ 
  ggtitle("Example text")
```

however, I get the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
In addition:
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: After `loadfonts` run `fonts()` do you see your font family in that vector?

Comment: @LMc Yes, I do see it.

Comment: If you see the font name and you're spelling it correctly as it's listed in the output from `fonts()` then I don't think you're doing anything wrong. Try changing the font and re-running your code to see if the font is changing. Otherwise, try changing `loadfonts(device = "pdf")` and see if you still have the warning.